# My wife’s always going on at me to dress better. & He’s always going on at me about fixing the door

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you please to explain these sentences?

> My wife’s always going on at me to dress better.

Does it mean that his wife wants to dress better or she thinks that her husband needs to dress better?

> He’s always going on at me about fixing the door.

Does it mean that he criticizes her that he always needs to fix the door after her actions or it means something else?

Comment: [Go on at someone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-go-on-at-sb) is an idiom meaning 'to complain to someone again and again about their behaviour or to ask them to do something'.

Comment: Please read my question.

Comment: @Sergey - Void clearly did read your question.

Comment: The wife wants her husband to dress better. Lacking context, it's unclear exactly what the other sentence means.

Comment: Is the sentence about fixing the door about the same couple as the one about dressing? Or is it different people? I understand that "he" is always complaining to "me" about fixing the door, as per Void's comment above re meaning of "going on at someone."

Comment: It's not the same couple. It's only examples from a dictionary. My questions are under the examples. My questions are not about what does it mean "go on at".

Comment: If it's necessary I can divide these examples.

Comment: @Sergey - consecutive examples in a dictionary are not necessarily linked. The people in the two examples are not necessarily or even probably the same people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My wife’s always going on at me to dress better.

My wife is always asking me to dress better, or complaining that I should dress better.

> He’s always going on at me about fixing the door.

He is always complaining to me because he thinks that I (or someone) needs to fix the door.

There is no gender implied for 'me' in the second example. The two examples are not linked.